# turning visible of my gif image off vb net

Tags: vb.net, image, gif

I have a gif image that I drew on code and then I animated the image using this code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class animatingimage

Inherits Form

'Create a Bitmpap Object. 
Private animatedImage As New Bitmap("E:\Data laptop\atom project\atom project etc\gambar2\Sprites fix\run\M\M_run_fixed\L\larikanan.gif")
Private currentlyAnimating As Boolean = False

'This method begins the animation. 
Public Sub AnimateImage()
    If Not currentlyAnimating Then

        'Begin the animation only once.
        ImageAnimator.Animate(animatedImage, New EventHandler(AddressOf Me.OnFrameChanged))
        currentlyAnimating = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub OnFrameChanged(ByVal o As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    'Force a call to the Paint event handler. 
    Me.Invalidate()
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)

    'Begin the animation.
    AnimateImage()

    'Get the next frame ready for rendering.
    ImageAnimator.UpdateFrames()

    'Draw the next frame in the animation.
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(Me.animatedImage, New Point(300, 300))


End Sub

Public Shared Sub Main()
    Application.Run(New animatingimage)
End Sub
```

Now, how to turn that image visibility false? I mean, to hide that image.

Comment: `ImageAnimator.StopAnimate`  [These guys know a lot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imageanimator_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) about the animator class

Comment: You'll have to stop calling DrawImage().  You re-invented the PictureBox control btw, it is just simpler to use it instead.  Set the Image property to Nothing.

Comment: what he is saying is that the PictureBox will natively animate GIFS without all that code.

Comment: I actually avoid using picture box because I'll have transparency problem with another image background. So I have to draw manually image using those codes. Do you guys have any simpler codes or ideas to draw gif and animating that gif without using picture box? please tell me, thanks

Comment: your transparency issue is not what you think.  you cant stack pictureboxes to let one image show thru to the other.  the thing "behind" each picturebox is the Form!

Comment: I know that rectangle shape of picturebox is passing through the other picturebox even I've put transparency backcolor to both of them. So, I'm trying to use codes above to draw a gif image and then animating the image. The problem is I want to make my image that I drew change to another image that I want to draw. Do you know how?